# Infinite sidescrolling terrain in Unity

Tags: unity, terrain, terrain-rendering

I am trying to create a horizontal line at the center of the screen that goes infinitely. I could make the line short and move it with the camera but the shape of my line actually changes as you progress. I am using a line renderer and I am not sure what is the best way to achieve this?

Secondly, the camera keeps moving to the right so I would like those parts of the line that are not visible anymore to get destroyed. I am also not sure how to achieve this since this is one big line I assume?

Comment: Can you be more precise? What does your line look like? What's its displacement? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Keep a fixed-size array of line segments wide enough to accommodate your camera at max zoom. These are fed into your `LineRenderer` via `.SetPositions()`.

```
struct LineSegment
{
   Vector2 p0;
   Vector2 p1; //this will be the same as p0 of the next segment
   Color color;
   //etc.
}

LineSegment[] lineSegments = new LineSegment[SIZE];
```

As you move right, you need to get the appropriate `LineSegment` inserted to the start or end of the array (depending on which way you are moving) and shift out old ones (leftmost):

```
//MOVE RIGHT
void MoveCameraRight()
{
    lineSegments[0] = null; //remove leftmost (you don't actually need this line)

    //shift all 1 segments to the left
    for (int i = 1; i < lineSegments.length; i++)
    {
        lineSegments[i - 1] = lineSegments[i];
    }

    //get the new rightmost segment
    lineSegments[lineSegments.length - 1] = RetrieveLineSegmentAt(i);
}

//move left - I'll leave this one to you! very similar.

void RetrieveLineSegmentAt(int i)
{
    //generate procedurally
    //OR
    //retrieve from some larger list, database, or whatever.
}
```

If you ensure that your line segments are always the same width in `x` (even if  tilted), you will always know exactly how many elements you need to fill the screen. I'd recommend this - it's easier. If, however, the rotation of individual line segment causes some to be narrower than others, like so:

```
    |\_
   /   \_
  |      \_
 /         \_
|            \_
^             ^
5 wide        10 wide
```

...then you will have to dynamically calculate how many you will need to fill the screen.

I would implement the whole terrain as a 1D heightmap, that is, just a sequence of heights at each evenly-spaced point. Your screen's `lineSegments` array can then be populated from the heightmap. This also means you can avoid dynamic width calculation, keeping things simple.